# Vim in tmux and WSL: cannot highlight using ctermbg

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, tmux, wsl2

I'm using Vim inside tmux, which runs in WSL (due to work reasons). As per documentation, I decided to change my `Visual` highlighting style using `:hi cterm=NONE ctermbg=<insert-color-here>`. However, this does not achieve the desired effect.

Afterwards, I changed to `guibg` and it works. Can anyone help me explain this?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `set termguicolors` is in configuration.

If it is in effect, `guibg` and `guifg` control background/foreground color of a chosen highlight group.